# Missing characters using read() from unistd.h

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port, std, unistd.h

We're using the `read()` method from `unistd.h` to receive data from the serial port in a Linux environment. To read data from `/dev/ttys1` specifically.

Part of the data we're receiving include the characters `0x0A` (line feed) and `0x0B` (vertical tab), but the library seems to ignore them.

I mean, we use an `unsigned char[]` to store the data obtained from the port, and the array contains all the data except those characters.

#### What do you think it could be wrong?

Comment: How did you open the file descriptor?  Sometimes certain options to the `open()` call can affect the data you get out of the file when reading.

Comment: unistd.h is not a library.  It is a header.

Comment: serial_fd = open( SerialPort, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK );

Comment: @WilliamPursell Ok, I get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ttys?  Are you sure to put the terminal driver in the correct state to pass out those characters?
(See tcgetattr and tcsetattr).  Depending on your precise setting, you can play interactively with those settings with the stty program.

Comment: We're receiving data and we used the 'tcsetattr()' before. so based in your suggestion we're looking for an attribute that could be causing the missing chars. thank you very much

Comment: @SDReyes: In particular, you probably want to use `cfmakeraw()` to set raw mode.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know you should be reading 0x0A and 0x0B ? Are you using any mechanism to "debug" the wire to be sure what is the message that you should be reading ?
The read() function makes no assumption about the data is reading, so if any bytes are lost, should be in any other part of your program.

Hopes this help you.
Thanks,
Sergio.

Comment: Hi Sergio -btw you have a very cool name, congrats-,

We have a .Net application that use the same device and it expects the 0x0A and 0x0B chars.